# unable to retrieve access token linkedin api

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am applying `connect with linkedin`. I'm following the [step by step guide](https://code.google.com/p/simple-linkedinphp/wiki/QuickStart). To authenticate users, I took help from [this](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication).

When the user clicks the `connect with linkedin` button the user is taken to the linkedin login page. After the user has given access to the account the user is redirected to:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=1ba8ogpm9e05&scope=r_basicprofile%20r_emailaddress&state=STATE&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8088/sandbox/linkedin/test.php
```

Through this, I get the authorization code. And pass it in the following url

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8088/sandbox/linkedin/final.php&client_id=1ba8ogpm9e05&client_secret=n7GN09I3F2L3IJD1
```

Here, the error comes i.e.

```
"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"missing required parameters, includes an invalid parameter value, parameter more then once. : Unable to retrieve access token : appId or redirect uri does not match authorization code or authorization code expired"
```

Where am I going wrong? I have double checked my api key and secret key.

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8088/sandbox/linkedin/final.php&client_id=1ba8ogpm9e05&client_secret=n7GN09I3F2L3IJD1

You have put AUTHORIZATION_CODE in place where it is required, right ? Let me know if you have done correctly..

Comment: Yes I am passing correct authorization code

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8088/sandbox/linkedin/final.php&client_id=1ba8ogpm9e05&client_secret=n7GN09I3F2L3IJD1
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=1ba8ogpm9e05&scope=r_basicprofile%20r_emailaddress&state=STATE&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8088/sandbox/linkedin/test.php
```

This both should contain same `redirect_uri` according to the [LinkedIn authentication guide](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication):

> **Parameter:** `redirect_uri`
> **Description:** Required. Same `redirect_uri` that you passed in the previous step.
> **Possible Errors:**
>
> - Different `redirect_uri` than used during authorization code generation
> - Passed an invalid value
> - Passed an empty or blank value
> - Missing the parameter

Comment: This was the case with me as well, except I was using same escaped redirect_uri but when I used non-escaped ones it went through!

Comment: @mkhatib Hi, I am getting invalid redirect_uri when I am using same redirect uri in authorization and accessToken end points. I tried with urls with and without encoding. The encoded url gives me the invalid redirect_uri error while the one without encoding gives the invalid request error. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error as you. I also met the following conditions:

- My request was a `POST` request.
- My `redirect_uri`'s were the same in `/authorization` and `/accessToken` calls.
- The `/accessToken` call was executed immediately after receiving the authorization code, so
  it wouldn't expire.

What finally did the trick for me was revoking the access token generated on the application details page on https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer.

This is an access token for oAuth 1.a and is not compatible with oAuth 2.0 on which the linkedIn api is currently running.
After revoking this access token I was able to get a new one with the `/authorization` and `/accessToken` calls.

Comment: I'm facing same issue, but i did not understand how you have revoked access token generated on application page? Can you help me for that? i'm using same redirectUri, still getting same problem

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to make sure you are sending the access token request as a 'POST'

Fissh

Comment: Can you tell me, i'm making POST request only, but what needs to be send in headers? and in the body too